# Máscaras em campos de formulário em modal woocommerce

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, woocommerce

Estou com um problema que creio que seja de simples solução, porem como sou leigo em javascript e jquery gostaria de um help de vocês.

Inseri dois campos novos na minha tela de login do woocommerce, campos esses de celular e cpf, ambos eu precisaria que tivessem máscaras.

Consegui através de pesquisas na internet o seguinte código em Jquery:

```html
/* Acionamento do arquivo javascript */

<?php

function mascara_cadastro_cliente(){
             
      if( is_page('minha-conta') )
      wp_enqueue_script('masked-input', 'http://meusite.com.br/wp-content/themes/flatsome-child'.'/js/jquery.maskedinput.min.js', array('jquery'));
  
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mascara_cadastro_cliente');


/* Inserção das máscaras nos campos CPF e Celular */

function activate_masked_input(){
   if( is_page('minha-conta') ){
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery( function($){
                      
                     jQuery("#reg_billing_cpf").mask("999.999.999-99");
                     jQuery("#reg_billing_cellphone").mask("(99)99999-9999");
                });
 
         </script>
 

<?php 
   }
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'activate_masked_input');
?>
```

Esse código funciona perfeitamente, porem somente em uma janela comum, o problema aparece agora, minha tela de login e cadastro é em modal, sendo assim, mesmo inserindo em is_page() o nome da página que se encontra o login e cadastro o mesmo não funciona, porém se eu abrir a mesma página em outra aba, sem ser em modal as máscaras funcionam perfeitamente. A impressão que eu tenho é que quando aberto em modal o código javascript não é acionado pela página minha-conta.

Alguém poderia me dar uma ajudinha?